# Is there any PHP array_* function for extracting single values from a multidimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, array-filter, array-walk

If I have a multidimensional array, and I want to extract some of the data from it and place them in a new array, is there any existing `array_*()` function to do so?

For example, if I have the following array:

```
array(
    [
        'id'    => 1,
        'num'   => 200,
        'text'  => 'abc'
    ],
    [
        'id'    => 2,
        'num'   => 230,
        'text'  => 'def'
    ],
    [
        'id'    => 3,
        'num'   => 100,
        'text'  => 'ghi'
    ],

)
```

I would like to get the following resulting array:

```
[ 'abc', 'def', 'ghi' ]
```

Of course I can always do it manually using `foreach()` or something similar, but one-liners are always nice :)

Comment: Use `array_column($array, 'text');` with out use of foreach loop http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php

Comment: In fact your question is a perfect use case for `array_column`. Manual almost has the same example there http://php.net/array_column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try array_column function;

```
array_column(array $data, 'key')
```

Comment: have u tried that or just make -1

Comment: try first then vote and de-vote...i have tried and working for me

Comment: That works if you replace 'key' with 'text'

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

### You may use [array_map()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) in php

```
<?php
    $array = array([
            'id'    => 1,
            'num'   => 200,
            'text'  => 'abc'
        ],
        [
            'id'    => 2,
            'num'   => 230,
            'text'  => 'def'
        ],
        [
            'id'    => 3,
            'num'   => 100,
            'text'  => 'ghi'
        ],

    );


    $return = array_map(function ($value) {
        return  $value['text'];
    }, $array);

    echo "<pre>"; 
    print_R($return);
    ?>
```